# Facebook videos are not playing smoothly and does too much buffering?

Tags: ping

I am using MikroTik RouterBoard and YouTube videos or any other site videos plays very smoothly and fastly while Facebook Videos takes time in playing and also do not load much fast and also does alot of buffering and plays with stop ups so can anyone let me know what could be the problem??? while the facebook browsing is perfect also I am getting quite perfect ping response from facebook..!

> **Note :** I am not using any LoadBalancing besides I am using just one RB750GL and also I am using Google Open DNS..!

Facebook Ping At PC :
[image]

Facebook Ping At MikroTik Terminal :
[image]

Comment: I'd be running a packet capture using something like wireshark. Also, the videos hosted on facebook may or may not be hosted on the same servers that the facebook.com application resides. It wouldn't surprise me if the videos/pictures are on a CDN somewhere so pinging facebook probably won't reveal anything.

Comment: Seems to be resolved little bit better while using my own ISP DNS Server instead of using Google Public DNS or OpenDNS..!

Comment: You haven't described the network. What switches or other devices do you have on your network, and how have you configured QoS? What other applications are running on the network? What do your device logs say? What other troubleshooting have you done?